# amsmath & formatting problem: equation over-runs solution box

Tags: formatting, amsmath, line-breaking

In this math exercise solution set, the **solution** over-runs the solution box. Here's the current rendering:

[image]

There should be a line break immediately following the `=`. I can't achieve this with either `\\` or `\bigskip`.

Thanks very much for taking time to read and respond to this post!

mwe:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\printanswers
% un-comment to print solutions.
\renewcommand{\solutiontitle}{}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0.5in,include head]{geometry}
\usepackage{systeme}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{soul}
\pagestyle{head}
\header{Algebra II: Problem Set D}
       {}
       {Due 04/07/23} 

\newcommand{\pagetop}{%
\noindent 
  
  \bigskip
  \vspace{0.5mm}
}

\settasks{after-item-skip=1em,
          after-skip=2cm,
          label-width=1.5em, %<---------
          item-indent=2em,   %<---------
          label=(\arabic*),
          column-sep=1em     %<----------
          }
\begin{document}
%definition for bigskip = 1 line to replace all \bigskip
\def\bigskip{\vskip\bigskipamount}

\textbf{Solve each system algebraically.}
\begin{tasks}
[style=enumerate](2)
% Prob #1
\task 
\systeme{
  x^2+y^2 = 41,
  x^2-y^2 = 9
  }
\bigskip
\begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
Add the equations to eliminate $y^2$ term.
\bigskip
$2x^2=50$
\bigskip
$\dfrac{\cancel{2}x^2}{\cancel{2}} = {\dfrac{50}{2}}$
\bigskip
$\sqrt{x^2}=\pm\sqrt{25}$
\bigskip
\colorbox{yellow}{$\bm{x=\pm5}$}
\bigskip
Substitute $x=5$ into one of the equations and solve for $y$.
\bigskip
Alternatively, substituting $x=-5$ produces the same result ($y=\pm4$).\\ 
\\
$(5)^2+y^2=41$
\bigskip
$25+y^2=41$
\bigskip
$y^2=16$
\bigskip
$\sqrt{y^2}=\pm\sqrt{16}$
\bigskip
\colorbox{yellow}{$\bm{y=\pm4}$}
\bigskip
\colorbox{yellow}{$\bm{Solutions:(\pm5,\pm4)=
(5,4)(5,-4)(-5,4)(-5,-4}$}
\end{solutionorbox}
\vspace{0.25cm}


\end{tasks}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing your code to focus it on the problem you wish to fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LaTeX code that gives rise to the issue you wish to fix is:

```
\colorbox{yellow}{$\bm{Solutions:(\pm5,\pm4)=(5,4)(5,-4)(-5,4)(-5,-4}$}
```

There are (at least) three issues: (i) the second argument of `\colorbox` does not get line-broken automatically; (ii) why is "Solutions:" being rendered in math mode? (iii) Why do you use both **bold-facing** *and* color-highlighting for emphasis? Using one or the other method for catching the reader's attention should be more than enough.

The following screenshot shows the original problem along with two possible fixes: (a) introduce explicit line breaks; (b) don't use both `\bm` *and* color-highlighting. Both solutions render the word "Solutions:" in text mode instead of in math mode.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\printanswers
\renewcommand{\solutiontitle}{}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{systeme}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0.5in,includehead]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{soul}
\pagestyle{head}
\header{Algebra II: Problem Set D}{}{Due 04/07/23} 

\newcommand{\pagetop}{\bigskip\noindent\vspace{0.5mm}}

\settasks{after-item-skip=1em,
          after-skip=2cm,
          label-width=1.5em, %<---------
          item-indent=2em,   %<---------
          label=(\arabic*),
          column-sep=1em     %<----------
          }

%definition for bigskip = 1 line to replace all \bigskip
\def\bigskip{\vskip\bigskipamount}

\begin{document}

\textbf{Solve each system algebraically.}

\begin{tasks}[style=enumerate](2)

% Prob #1
\task 
\systeme{
  x^2+y^2 = 41,
  x^2-y^2 = 9
  }
\bigskip
\begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
\bigskip
\dots
\bigskip
\colorbox{yellow}{$\bm{Solutions:(\pm5,\pm4)=(5,4)(5,-4)(-5,4)(-5,-4)}$}
\bigskip
\textbf{Solutions: }\colorbox{yellow}{$\bm{(\pm5,\pm4)=(5,4)\,(5,-4)}$} 

\hspace{3.5cm}\colorbox{yellow}{$\bm{\,(-5,4)\,(-5,-4)}$}
\bigskip
\textbf{Solutions:}

\colorbox{yellow}{$(\pm5,\pm4)=(5,4)\,(5,-4)\,(-5,4)\,(-5,-4)$}
\end{solutionorbox}
\vspace{0.25cm}

\end{tasks}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for both OP edit and the solution. In the future, I will be mindful of only including enough of the math exercise problems for community members to compile and see the error. Your explanation of why the original code failed to produce the desire line break was most helpful! Agree that both bold and highlighting is overkill. For my high school math students, do you have preference between the two options?

Comment: Solution is great! Many thanks! Could you please explain why when compiled in overleaf, your revised code kicks out this error: ```
```Package tasks Warning: You've placed \par before the first \task on line 58. I will throw it away and ignore it for the rest of the list.```

Comment: @SiuslawMath - It's a warning message, *not* an error message. You may safely ignore it. 'm afraid I'm not sufficiently well versed with the `exam` document class and its many environments to be able to determine rapidly what may be triggering this warning message.

Comment: @SiuslawMath - Regarding the question in your first comment: I'm afraid I'm too old to be in a position to credibly claim to know what the current generation of high school age students do and do not prefer. :-) That said, speaking for myself, I'd go with the color method.

Comment: Me thinks students primarily prefer cell phones and TikTok. :) To generate  this kind of worksheet with solution box print/no print option, would it be more efficient to use a different doc class instead of ```exam```? Thank you!

Comment: @SiuslawMath - Since it's a (most likely entirely innocuous) warning message, I'd keep using the `exam` document class unless you've encountered other, real shortcomings with it. If you feel sufficiently motivated, you could contact the Philip Hirschhorn (the maintainer of the [exam](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/exam) package) by email, send him my code, and ask him if there's an issue in the either that code or in some part of the `exam` package.

Comment: Thanks for your response and recommendation re: Mr. Hirschhorn!